# Dynamodb Query Filter expression not returning record

Tags: node.js, lambda, dynamodb-queries

I'm running a query within a nodejs Lambda service.  The service/query executes with no errors, but is not returning a record I know exists in the Dynamodb table.

The query:

```js
const getRecords = async (event) => {
  console.log("get specific Record")
  try {
    const dog = event.pathParameters.dogid
    const user = event.queryStringParameters.userId
    const params = {
      TableName: tableName,
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#dogId": "dogId",
        "#userId": "userId"
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":dogId": {
          S: `${dog}`
        },
        ":userId": {
          S: `${user}`
        }
      },
      KeyConditionExpression: "#dogId = :dogId",
      FilterExpression: "#userId = :userId"
    }
    const { Item } = await dbClient.send(new QueryCommand(params))

    console.log("Item :", Item)
    return Item ? unmarshall(Item) : {}
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
    throw e
  }
}
```

The tableName 'dog' has a PK dogId and a Sort Key PledgeId.
I want to return all records for the dog and a particular user - I don't want to provide the pledgeId for this query, but used elsewhere in other working queries.

Comment: If you temporarily disable the filter and just query on dogId, do you get all the items for that dog ID, including the ones you think you should get with the matching userId?

Comment: Good idea.  And I'm not getting the record back if I just use dogId.  I have another query (separate Lambda) that uses this query, but it's using getItem.  const params = {
  TableName: tableName,
  Key: {
    dogId: { S: `${event.pathParameters.dogid}` }
  }
}
const { Item } = await dbClient.send(new GetItemCommand(params)). - This does return the record.

Comment: Have you logged the event and the subsequent dog & user variables? Do they have the values you expected?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue after some testing.  Thanks @jarmod for helping me break down the issue.

I was returning a single item to the body response, but wanted multiple records.  I've changed to this and it works as expected.

```
try {
    const { Items } = await dbClient.send(new QueryCommand(params))
    return Items ? Items.map((item) => unmarshall(item)) : {}
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
    throw e
}
```

Comment: Note that you're returning an array if `Items` is present (it's not nullish) and an object if `Items` is absent. Probably better to be consistent and return\ an array in both cases.